# Firestore query with array of strings

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make social network (like instagram )

User have posts and followers etc

I want for home feed show posts just from users i follow.

User have array with ids of users he follow. So idea is to query from colloection “Posts” where id is equal to one of ids and sort them by timestamp and limit them.

I could make for loop for each in following array but this will be unusable for more than 100 following users.

Edit how I think it could be solved

Hello i dont know if im doing it right but here is my solution for social network like instagram or any other where one user follow other users and have feed from their posts ordered by date.

Each user have its own Collection Timeline where are posts references (postId, createdAt, createdBy) that user should see at his feed, when user start following other user it will put all his posts to feed. For display feed I just call on User timeline, sort it by date and request just 25 of them.

[image: data structure of user]

When user start the app I loop trough all followers and request their posts younger than lastTimeline timestamp from their posts collection if they have any I add them to timeline.

I would be happy for your opinion.

Comment: This is as far too broad as it gets.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how make this ? Or change data structure? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the followed user ID and then request the first 5 posts of each one.
Or use some kind of paging

Comment: But this will be bad if you have 1000 users which you follow. Thousand of calls so i will get 5k posts and than order them ? I write here because i was desperate but i found this. Basically you manage timeline for each user also insane.                               Link - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1

Comment: It's unlikely that someone has to follow 1.000 users and every posts. That would basically mean that he/she spends more than 20 hours per day reading posts...
If it is actually the case, then there is no way around getting and sorting the posts. 
The best way do proceed then, is paging users. First get the first 10 users, with their top 5 posts and offer the user the possibility to request the 10 next users and so on...